# Is it safe to push a sqilte file to public repo?

Tags: python-3.x, database, git, sqlite

I am using `sqlite3` with Python and I have a `.db` file in my project, and it has all the details related to the user, the password hashes, the salt used for hashing, the username, etc. And this file is on a local git repo. I do have a remote public repo for this project. But I was concerned if pushing the database file to a public repo might be a good idea?

Should I make the repo private? Or should I add this file to the `.gitignore` list and make a way to generate the database and the tables on the fly with empty data?

Or is there a way to protect the database with a username and password kinda like in MySQL, not exactly like that, as MySQL runs on a server and you enter the username and password for using the server rather than a specific database?

I know it might be a better idea to use some cloud-based DB with APIs and all, but this is just a basic level project and I don't have much experience related to cloud-based DBs, but the user might provide actual sensitive data.

So is it a safe option to push the `.db` file to the public remote repo?

Comment: As a general rule, one should never put any sensitive data into any public space. That's not just about Git and hosting sites, but about *all* sensitive data, and *all* storage sites. The number of security breaches because someone dropped credit card numbers into some AWS bucket that's globally readable by everyone is ridiculous.

Answer (score 1):

Git, as any other CVS (Concurrent Versioning System), is designed to store source code, and all the files, binary included (possibly by **Git LFS**), which cannot be generated on demand by tools, source code or scripts.

About the specific case of a database, you should provided DDL scripts to reproduce the DB schema, and the SQL code, evicted of reserved data, to populate it again.

A good approach would be to introduce place holders inside SQL files, and scripts which require sensitive data to substitute to the above place holders.